# how to hide onStepContinue button for the last step and onStepCancel for the first step on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my first time on flutter framework and Dart programming I have so manny miss of understanding Dart language.

I want to hide onStepContinue button for the last step and onStepCancel for the first step on flutter? this is my code I'm newbe in flutter any help?

> ```
> class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
>   int _currentStep = 0;
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(
>         title: Text(widget.title),
>       ),
>       body: Center(
>         child: Stepper(
>           controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details) {
>             return Row(
>               children: <Widget>[
>               TextButton(
>                 onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
>                 child: const Text('NEXT'),
>               ),
>               TextButton(
>                 onPressed: details.onStepCancel,
>                 child: const Text('BACK'),
>               ),
>             ],
>             );
>           },
>           steps: const [
>             Step(
>               title: Text("Step 1"),
>               content: Text("Information for step 1"),
>             ),
>             Step(
>               title: Text("Step 2"),
>               content: Text("Information for step 2"),
>             ),
>             Step(
>               title: Text("Step 3"),
>               content: Text("Information for step 3"),
>             ),
>           ],
>           onStepTapped: (int newIndex){
>             setState(() {
>               _currentStep = newIndex;
>             });
>           },
>           currentStep: _currentStep,
>           onStepContinue: () {
>             if (_currentStep != 2) {
>               setState(() {
>                 _currentStep += 1;
>               });
>             }
>           },
>           onStepCancel: () {
>             if (_currentStep != 0) {
>               setState(() {
>                 _currentStep -= 1;
>               });
>             }
>           },
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have added the detail thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional state to show the buttons.

```dart
controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details) {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      if (_currentStep != 2) // skip on last step
        TextButton(
          onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
          child: const Text('NEXT'),
        ),
      if (_currentStep != 0)// skip on 1st step   
         TextButton(
          onPressed: details.onStepCancel,
          child: const Text('BACK'),
        ),
    ],
  );
},
```

Comment: works fine, thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to help you out, check more about [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget using Visibility like this,

```
bool goneVisibilty=true;

Visibility(
  child: Text("Gone"),//replace with your widget
  visible: goneVisibility,
),
```

when ever u need to update this widget call setState to update.

```
setState((){
goneVisibility=false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the respone but we need to use the condition because when we call the setState in widget all of the button there will disappear and I only need for the first and for the end stepper

Comment: wrap with only FirstStep Button inside Visibility, in scope u make firstButtonVisibilty=true, when your condition satisfies then make firstButtonVisibility=false;

Answer (score 0):

**To Enable/Disable Button you can use this**

```
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      int _counter = 0;
      bool _isButtonDisabled;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        _isButtonDisabled = false;
      }
    
      void _incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
          _isButtonDisabled = true;
          _counter++;
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("The App"),
          ),
          body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                new Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                ),
                _buildCounterButton(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget _buildCounterButton() {
        return new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text(
            _isButtonDisabled ? "Hold on..." : "Increment"
          ),
          onPressed: _isButtonDisabled ? null : _incrementCounter,
        );
      }
    }
```